# Symfony Annotations are not parsed

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, fosuserbundle

I have installed the FOSUserBundle and installed it as per its detailed installation guide (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md).

When i run php console doctrine:schema:update --force for the first time, it populates the users table with all of the default fields that the FOSUserBundle has defined.

Unfortunately it appears to be completely missing the fields which i have added to my user entity and i am wondering if its utilising the configuration file which is specified in the installation guide instead of using the annotations which are in the entity.

It also appears to be ignoring the other entities within the same Bundle.

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User extends BaseUser {

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bureau", mappedBy="id")
 */
protected $bureau;

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

This is my user entity, of which bureau is being completely ignored regardless if it has a relationship or not.

**Edit**

As per requested, please find below the orm config file. It's the default file as per the configuration.

I have suspected this to be the problem, but i wasnt sure if annotations and the config file could work together.

```yaml
Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    type:  entity
    table: users
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
```

**Edit 2**
I have found that if i remove the orm configuration file that it all magically works again!!

So i would adjust my question for clarity.

**Updated question**
If an orm configuration file exists, are annotations ignored?

Comment: Lets have a looksie at your doctrine orm setup in your config.yml file.

Comment: I meant your root config. `app/config.yml`.  just the `orm` part.

Comment: Sorry, miss understood, here is the orm section of my config.yml.    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you generate entities with the console, you are asked on the format, which is:

- xml
- yaml
- annotations

Regardless of what you choose, there are no signifiers telling Doctrine which to use besides the fact one exists.  In order, YAML takes priority over annotations, and so it should.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and sorry again for being dense. The entities was generated manually which is what was causing confusion for me, now i understand what is happening it wont happen again.